# How can I save text input when my textbox is in resourcedictionary?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have 2 projects in the solution explorer. One has the resource dictionary located in the folder called "Themes". The other project is set to main startup, which has the MainWindow.xaml and MainWindow.xaml.cs. I'm just wondering if I could save whatever text I will input in the textbox coded in my resource dictionary and still there the next time I open the app
The code would like this:

```
<TextBox telerik:PersistenceManager.StorageId="myText"    
         IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled}" 
         Text="{Binding Notes, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
         AcceptsReturn="True" 
         TextWrapping="Wrap" 
         BorderThickness="0"                 
         ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
         Background="{x:Null}" Foreground="White" />
```

I tried to merged my resourcedictionary to MainWindow.xaml, but still can't
access the textbox when I write a  code behind inside the MainWindow.xaml.cs.

How should I do this? I don't have any Idea what to do.
I would appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: Store the text somewhere like in a database if you want it the next time you open the app.

Comment: You may be confusing the concept of binding to data verses data storage. A resource dictionary is simply a library of styles and has nothing to do with data processing.

Comment: Okay thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Use application settings to persist data between sessions for a user. See 
[Managing Application Settings (.NET)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a65txexh.aspx).

Comment: Thanks I got it ...but is it possible to code behind resource dictionary? I want to add new event handler with some of my data templates...

Comment: @Fred From what you have described, adding an *event handler* in a style in a resource dictionary cannot be done. But to create styles which handle data states can be done with style triggers and data triggers.